# how to search nested JSON object property

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to drill down a array of objects for a ng-repeat. the nested object has properties that i have never seen before. not even sure what to search for.

fiddler[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ksfruvms/2/)

```
0: Object
   Id: 1
   OutputFilePath: null
   ParameterData: Object
        {CBSA}: "Abilene, TX"
```

I need get the value of

> CBSA

Comment: is there any way you could post some of your code that you've written and/or a fiddle?

Comment: have you tried Object.keys()? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @Jesse just made a fiddler with data. didnt know what to start with so i have nothing that i have tried to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an odd property name. However you can access it like:

```
{{item.ParameterData['{CBSA}']}}
```